# Setting global variable for the entire unit test case

Tags: php, codeception

I have declared a public variable and set its value in the first test case.
But,When I try to access the value of the same variable in the second test case it returns blank value.

```
class ClassFailedLoginTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    protected $tester;
    public $user_id;

    public function testA(){
       $this->user_id = '100';
    }

    public function testB(){
       //The assertion fails as $this->user_id returns empty.
       assertTrue($this->user_id == 100,"Expected: 100, Actual: {this>user_id}");
    }
```

Comment: `testB()` should call `testA()` or init the variable in the class:  `public $user_id = 100;`

Comment: Basically, I needed to have a record in the database and use the same record throughout the whole unit test. Is there a way out?
I don't want to call testA in testB I want to assign the value to a variable once and use it through out the test.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in your case You can do this:

create a class related to `ClassFailedLoginTest` in bootstrap file.

bootstrap.php

```
class ClassFailedLoginTestData {
    public static $user_id;
}
```

and in your test case:

```
class ClassFailedLoginTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    protected $tester;

    public function testA(){
       ClassFailedLoginTestData::$user_id = '100';
    }

    public function testB(){
       //The assertion fails as $this->user_id returns empty.
       assertTrue(ClassFailedLoginTestData::$user_id == 100,"Expected: 100, Actual: {this>user_id}");
    }
}
```

also you can init that class in your test class property for easier access.

Answer (score 1):

It`s easy, you are looking for for method _before which is executing
before each test case.

Basic concept of unit testing is the tests does not depend on each other. So even if you call only testB it should passed. Do not call other test inside test method. It`s bad practice.

With _before method it will look something like this.

```
class ClassFailedLoginTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{

    protected $tester;

    private $user_id;



    protected function _before()
    {
        parent::_before();
        $this->user_id = '100';
    }



    public function testA()
    {
        // some assert
    }



    public function testB()
    {
        assertTrue($this->user_id == 100, "Expected: 100, Actual: {this>user_id}");
    }
}
```

BTW is good habit to always call parent:: for method which you override from library, you never know if implementation will change in next version.

Comment: But _before method is called every time before a test is executed ,I didnt need multiple records.I just want to have a single record.Ie single insert.

Comment: Is there any method which will run only once per test file? like "setup" or "bootstrap". but once per test file?

I tried __construct(); but it seems codeception creates new instance for every test execution.

Comment: I think you little misunderstood unit testing, first of all, unit test should work without any dependency - so it should run without database. So you can mock the connection. If you want to write test with using database, you should create a database with a test data in transaction and on the end of one test the transaction should be rollbacked to have each test as separated as possible.